# inserting element into list of ascending order [ocaml]

Tags: sorting, ocaml

the following code inserts an element into a list sorted in ascending order.

```
let rec insert x l =
  match l with
    | [] -> [x]
    | y::ys -> if x < y then x::y::ys else y::insert x ys
```

However, how do I implement the above function just using List.fold_right, and no recursion?

Comment: `fold_right` is recursion

Comment: what I meant is that I want the code to look like... 'let insert x l = ...' and not 'let rec insert x l = ... '

Comment: I do not see why you want to use fold for insert. fold must scan all the list element but insert needs not. If it is a homework, it is not a good one and might confuse you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the simplest implementation of `List.fold_right`:

```
let rec fold_right f li init = match li with
  | [] -> init
  | y::ys -> f y (fold_right f ys init)
```

You could try something like

```
let insert x li =
  let add_x y inserted_ys =
    if x < y then x::y::inserted_ys
    else y::inserted_ys
  in
  List.fold_right add_x li [x]
```

The problem is that the `then` branch is not correct: you will get `x` in two places, both at the beginning of the list, and in `inserted_ys`. However, you know at which position `x` will be in the `inserted_ys` list: right at the beginning, as all elements of `ys` are greater than `x`. So you can just remove `x` with `List.tl`.

```
let insert x li =
  let add_x y inserted_ys =
    if x < y then x::y::(List.tl inserted_ys)
    else y::inserted_ys
  in
  List.fold_right add_x li [x]
```

Remark that this is a complicated way to write `insert`. A better technique would be to have `add_x` return a pair of a list and a boolean, the boolean telling you if `x` has already been added or not yet.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that the scheme for the solution is something like this:

```
fun insert x l =
    List.fold_right (fun a b -> if <test> then a :: x :: b else a :: b) l []
```

Each time the function gets called, it sees the end of the final list, and the new element that would normally go next in front of the list. It seems possible to decide whether or not to insert your value `x` at the current position based on this information.

A naive implementation of this scheme will insert x many times into the result. But it seems to me it will work if you make the `<test>` specific enough.

This scheme also doesn't work when x belongs at the beginning of the list. You would have to handle that case separately.

As gasche says, this is not an effective way to build ascending list. (FWIW gasche is a far more knowlegeable OCaml expert than I :-)